# Java - Search rectangle in an array(efficient way to do so)

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have an array which contains an object, which has different variables in it (rectangle, image and etc...)

I am looking for an efficient way to save the array, and an efficient way to search through it.

I need to search every time all of the objects that their rectangle is inside the range of rendering

Is there a good, efficient, and fast way to do so?

Comment: Is it an array of interfaces? or just an array of one object?

Comment: I would highly recommend adding more details. What are the different objects in your array. What are their relative size or structure ?
Where are you trying to save it ? File or Database ?

Comment: @jacob ArrayList<Tile> , tile is a class I made which contains everything about the tile (rectangle, sprite etc..)

Comment: @MithunS , I have an ArrayList<Tile>, tile is a class I made which contains everything about the tile(rectangle, sprite, etc..).
I am looking for a way to efficiently search through the array to find the tiles that their rectangles location is inside a certain range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how often you modify your "things to be rendered" array compared to how often you try to search things in it, you might profit from a different way of looking at your data. Let's say that you only occasionally modify the array, so you have some array of Renderable objects where each Renderable has a getOutline() that returns a rectangle:

```
Renderable[] arr = new Renderable[] { /* whatever */ };
```

A canonical solution for speeding up frequent searches would be to sort the array according to the property you search by, and then use binary searches which are O(log n) instead of O(n) like traversing the array would be. In this case you cannot do that because you are basically indexing on 2/4 properties/keys: the X extent and the Y extent of each rectangle.

What you can do is have *four* arrays made up of the same objects (as they are references, the space cost is not large) and each one is sorted by one of four properties of the corresponding rectangles: the "top" (min Y), "bottom" (max T), "left" (min X) and "right" (max X). For example you would define one of them like:

```
Comparator<Renderable> topComp = (r1, r2) -> r1.getOutline().top - r2.getOutline().top;
Renderable[] byTop = Arrays.stream(arr).sorted(topComp).toArray(Renderable[]::new);
// The same goes for byBottom, byLeft and byRight
```

The first line in the middle creates a Comparator using a lambda that imposes an ordering on your Renderable objects that is the same as that of the natural ordering of their top coordinates. It could be replaced by `Comparator.comparingInt(r -> r.getOutline().top);` since the Comparator interface has static methods to create comparation objects that do just this.

Now, when you have a region to draw on, you can use binary searches to quickly find which rectangles overlap it:

```
// We'll say that the variable "reg" contains a rectangle that needs to be redrawn
// We'll make it a fake Renderable so "it" can be searched in the arrays
Renderable rReg = new FakeRenderable(reg);
int topPos    = Arrays.binarySearch(byTop,    rReg, topComp);
int bottomPos = Arrays.binarySearch(byBottom, rReg, bottomComp);
// etc for leftPos and rightPos
```

After performing 4 O(log n) lookups, each xPos variable may be either positive or negative.

- If positive (or zero), that means that the index returned is that of the first object in the array that is *equal* to the given key. The index partitions the array into "lesser than the key" and "greater or equal than the key" - if you wanted to leave the "equal" objects in the left side, just search for a key that is one greater.
- If negative, no object was exactly equal to your key, and the value is (-(insertion point) - 1), where the insertion point is the index of the first element *greater* than the key. Thus, `iFirstGreater = -(x + 1);` where x is the value returned by binarySearch. Then, `iFirstGreater` partitions the array into "lesser than the key" and "greater than the key".

Thus, in any case the indices partition the four arrays. You have four indices into four sorted arrays telling you which renderables have a "top" coordinate above/below your region's top, which have a "bottom" above/below that of your region, and the same for the left and right fields. Using that information, you can decide whether each renderable object is

- Outside of the drawing area (and it should be ignored)
- Inside the drawing area (and it should be drawn in full)
- Overlapping the drawing area (and it should be drawn partially/clipped)

Comment: Thank you very much :)
It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Rectangle rectangle : array) {
     // check rectangle
}
```

Comment: Throwing code at the reader isn't very useful. Please identify the core issue in the question, what has been done to resolve it, and why.

Comment: Please look at what I wrote, I am searching for a fast and efficient way. Thats the basic way to do it, and its not really efficient and rather slow. 
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going through all elements in the array, there is really not anything to it. Simply iterate through all elements and check each rectangle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    Rectangle r = myArray[i].rectangle;
    //do something with r
}
```

Comment: Please look at what I wrote, I am searching for a fast and efficient way.
Thats the basic way to do it, and its not really efficient and rather slow.
Thanks anyways

Comment: @PazHaviv If you had to choose between some objects and leave the other objects and had to find a way to know how to search to find the objects that you want, that would be a different things. You want to check EVERY object as far as I can tell, so there is no other way than simply checking every object.

Comment: I want to check which rectangles are in the range of the players view. I marked an answer which Javier Martin gave me, which is a good an efficient one

Comment: Yeah, but you don't know if all of the objects in your list are actually rectangles. Your question says that. Thats why everyone is saying, you need to go through the list to first of all identify if the object is even a rectangle or not. 
The assumption of the answer above is not fully correct, what if the object is not a rectangle ? How will you deal with it then ?

Comment: @MithunS as far as I understand it there is an array of objects which all have a rectangle (among other things) as attribute and he wants to check all the rectangles in the fastest way possible.

Comment: @MithunS like what gendarme said, there is an array of objects which all have a rectangle.